# apply bindings from external file

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I have my external file that I want my knockout to sit in, with this code:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
var counties = ko.observableArray([]);

this.getCounties = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Search/ByCounty',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data && data.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var obj = data[i];
                    counties.push(obj.CountyName);
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
};
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Then on my MVC view page called search.cshtml, I call the above like so:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: getCounties">getCounties</button>
```

This seems to push all the data into the array, then the next aspect I would like to do is loop the counties, like so:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Counties</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: counties">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: CountyName"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The error I get is:

Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function(){return counties }"
Message: counties is not defined

I don't get it, getCounties is called on the click event there so can't it get the values from the array? This has something to do with scope I think but I cannot fathom it, I'm sure there is very simple explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the binding to work, `countries` should be a property of the object used in `ko.applyBindings()`. Currently you're just populating a local variable called `countries`. Change your code to:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  this.counties = ko.observableArray([]);
  this.getCounties = function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/Search/ByCounty',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(data) {
        if (data && data.length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var obj = data[i];
            self.counties.push(obj.CountyName);
          }
        }
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Inside the ajax success callback, `this` refers to the `jqXHR` object. So, you need to keep a reference `self` to the viewModel outside and use `self.counties.push()` inside the callback.

This still won't display the countries for you. Because, according to your bindings, knockout looks for `CountyName` property inside each `countries`. So, you need to push entire object like this `self.counties.push(obj)`.

Or,

if you wish to keep `countries` as a string array, you can use the [`$data`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-1-referring-to-each-array-entry-using-data) keyword to refer to the current `country` in context of the loop:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: counties">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```